# "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value" gives an ugly error

Tags: iis-7, custom-errors

Robots are trying to hack my IIS site using Apache exploits again.

The w00tw00t attacks return the yellow screen of death instead of using the custom error page as defined in web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/error"/>
```

Any suggestions on how to get IIS to do the right thing here and redirect them?